# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types exception on my dev machine

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package

In my team, a dev recently updated our project to use EF6.
All my colleagues can run the projet whitout problems, but in my machine, I'm getting the error:

"Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found."

This package is not even being used in the project, no one of my team even has the dll in the project.

I cant seem to find out what is wrong with this.

Can anyone help me?

Using Visual Studio 19.6.3 and SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Do all your colleagues have SQL Server installed on their machines?

Comment: Did you add the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package?

Comment: @strickt01 yes, and I have installed it also.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thats not what it is supposed to be done. neither of my colleagues has the package installed.

Comment: Already installed the SQLSysClrTypes update for Microsoft 2016 and still doenst work...

Comment: Thisis the piece of code that is breaking  listGrupos = grupos.Include("Area_Geometry").Include("Area_Geometry.Area_Geometry_Shape").ToList();

Comment: Done. Had to install SQL Server 2016 LocalDB on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem, you need SQL Server installed in your machine.

If you have windows 10 in your system, check if you have SQL Server installed in **Apps and features**.

[image]

You can also check if you have any version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in your GAC_MSIL (Global Assembly Cache) directory on C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, if this folder is empty or does not exist, you will need to install Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in your machine.